# Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

Tags: jsp

My Code is

```
public String split(String line)
{
char[] temp = line.toCharArray();
String get = "";
for(int i = 0;i < line.length();i++)
    {
    if(temp[i] == ',')
        {
        return get;
        get = "";
        }
    get = get + temp[i];
    }
}
```

I am working on Eclipse(Indigo). It gives an error "Syntax error on token "(", ; expected".

Comment: I don't know about the token error. But you are sure missing a return statement.

Comment: This probably doesn't have anything to do with your error message, but in your `if(temp[i] == ',')` block, you're returning `get` and then setting it? You realize that `get = "";` is never going to get called, right? And your function is misnamed; this doesn't split a line, it returns everything up to the first comma.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, with respect to parentheses. Your title says the error is a close paren, but your question body says the error is on an open paren. Which line of code is the debugger highlighting as the problem line?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Java is confusing your split declaration with the split function that is part of Java's string class.  So when the compiler hits the close paren of your `split(String line)` declaration, it gets confused because it thinks you're trying to call Java's `String` `split()` function, so it is expecting you to close the call with a semicolon.

Use the [split function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) that already exists in the Java platform, or give your `split` function a different name, like `mySplit`.  That should clear up the compiler error.

Comment: i have used Split, got error, "The method split(String) is undefined for the type Object"

Comment: Try `String[] result = myString.split();` See here: http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-split-example

Answer (score 0):

You have a return get; then set it you can't do that. The get= ""; never gets called because it returns before it sets it.

Comment: Okay. Is there any function which split string, i mean i have used split(), but it gives error. I have used it like that

Comment: string example = "My name is, khak"; example.split();. Eclipse gives error

Comment: How do you want to split it? By each letter, by whitespace?